# Numpy: choose, where, partition or something else?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to filter an array as follows:

```
[[[   512    520      1 130523]]

 [[  1554   1793   1661  56337]]

 [[  1327   1553   1433  52386]]

 [[  1799   2049   1931  51753]]

 [[   958   1313   1107  49546]]

 [[   625    770    706   8822]]

 [[     2    492    297  36816]]

 [[   520    614    573   7448]]

 [[  1313   1327   1321   1086]]]
```

I want to match the fourth column against some condition (let's say >50000) and remove the row if it doesn't match, keep it if it does.

I'm struggling with the numpy docs to work out what to do. I have quite a few of these to do so any extra tips on sorting/filtering would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a 3-d array. Is that intended?

Comment: That's what I've got at this point in my code. I need to maintain the format as it's going into other functions that will interpret it as is. (it's a list of coordinates and distances that are to be plotted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is really the shape it has to be, and optically it seems to be (9,1,4), then you can create a simple mask index array in the following way:

Let's say your array name is "x"

then:

```
indices = x[:,:,3] > 50000
x = x[numpy.where(indices)[0]]
```

indices is then a boolean array of the same shape as x and contains.

This also works, but doesn't maintain the shape as it seems:

```
x = x[indices]
```

EDIT: You can also instead of picking the valid lines go the other way and delete the invalid lines:

```
x = numpy.delete(x, numpy.where(~indices)[0], axis=0)
```

Comment: +1. there's no need to use `where`, `x[x[:,:,3]>50000]` will work already

Comment: It's not the same, since the shape is lost - at least when I try on my machine